# Is it possible to view protocol source code?

Tags: tcp, ip, protocols

Is it possible to view the source code of protocols such as TCP or IP? I am trying to really understand how things work and it feels like reading books about it only gets me so far, as it is indirectly and conceptually explaining how it works, and I want to actually look at the explicit code itself.

Comment: What source code? A protocol is an agreement of how software will behave - it isn't source code in itself. There are lots of *implementations* of protocols, and many of the TCP and IP implementations are open source.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of your best bet is to read Gary R. Wright & W. Richard Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated Vol. 2 - The Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163354X) (warning: commercial link).

This books contains the actual, *documented* source code of the 4.4BSD-Lite TCP/IP stack.

Be aware that 4.4BSD-Lite was released in 1994 though, so you should expect some of the content to be slightly outdated by today's standards.  That book remains a solid reference though.